# How to add array of objects to mongoDB model

Tags: express, mongoose

I have a model which represents a menu for a restaurant, within that model I have an array for the items in the menu. I am not sure how to add menu items to my menu model using express, I bolded the line where I am not sure what to write.

This is the menu model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const FoodItemSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  price: { type: Number, required: true },
  Category: { type: String, required: false },
  Quantity: { type: String, required: false },
});

const MenuSchema = new Schema({
  restaurant_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "restaurant" },
  items: [FoodItemSchema],
  dateCreated: { type: String, required: false },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("menu", MenuSchema);
```

And this is my express function which I am using to add menus to my database, I am unsure what to add for the array of menu items within the function.

```
exports.sendMenuData = (req, res) => {
  const menu = new Menu({
    restaurant_id: req.body.restaurant_id,
    **items: [FoodItemSchema]**, //Not sure what to write here in terms of req 
    dateCreated:req.dateCreated,
  });
  menu
    .save()
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: What are you sending in the request? I would assume some kind of JSON data that has the food items?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass through postman or whatever app you are using to acces your db the array of food items.

Example:

```
items: [req.body.theNameYouWant],
```

In postman:

theNameYouWant: {name:"Hot dog",price: 3,...(You must place here all the atributes of FoodItemSchema)}

Otherwise, you can also use operators such $addToSet $push which will allow you to introduce FoodItemSchema in the array.

Comment: Thank you for the help, what do I do if I want to add more than one food item at a time using postman.

Comment: You can use , after } and then open again brackets.